# How to get all the created beans in Quarkus

Tags: java, spring-boot, cdi, quarkus

I would like to get the list of beans that are created in a Quarkus service. For that I have the below piece of code. Is this the correct way to get it?

```
    @Inject
    BeanManager beanManager;

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        final String SPACE = " ";
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        final Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});
        for (final Bean<?> bean : beans) {
            LOGGER.info(counter.getAndIncrement() + SPACE + bean.getBeanClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

I have the same service in Spring Boot and I am trying to do exactly the same to know the list of beans that are created (the code is below).

```
    public static void displayAllBeans() {
        final String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        final String SPACE = " ";

        Arrays.stream(allBeanNames)
                .map(beanName -> new StringBuilder()
                        .append(counter.getAndIncrement())
                        .append(SPACE)
                        .append(beanName)
                        .toString())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

The result of the comparison is unbelievable. 18 beans are created in Quarkus vs 130 in Spring Boot. That is the reason I ask if I am getting the Quarkus beans in the correct way.

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: That looks correct on the first sight. You can also `@Inject Instance<Object>` instead of injecting the `BeanManager`, but that should give you roughly the same results (the only difference I can think of is that you will get directly the bean instances, instead of the bean metadata).